# Generate all permutations possible by deletion

Tags: java, math, guava, permutation

I need to generate all unique permutations that are possible by deleting one or more BIG characters of a String, while small characters shall remain untouched.

Example input:

```
AalAADBdBBDkCeCCA
```

Now I need to generate all permutations that are possible by

- removing one BIG character one or multiple times
- combining the removal of 1 to n BIG characters which are each removed 0 to m times (n = number of direct characters in the input, m = number of occurences of a character).
- leaving small characters untouched

I am only interested in unique permutations, that is, if the second or third (FIXED! originally I wrote first and second) A is removed makes no difference. Of course it however makes a difference if the first or last A is removed.

**Examples for permutations:**

```
AalAADBdBBDkCeCCA // original input also counts as permutation
AalAADBdBB kCeCCA // last D removed
 alAAD dBBDkCeCCA // first A and first B removed
Aal  D dBBDkCeC A  // second and third A removed, first B and last C removed
```

I am using Guava, in case this helps. A plain Java solution would be also fine.

I would also be interested if there is a name for this kind of permutation and some math formular giving the total amount of unique permutations, so one can verify the permutation algorithm result (at least in terms of correct amount of permutations).

*The example is a reduced problem, it can be assumed that the input is already available as a List of characters or whatever else pre-parsed format instead of a merged String.*

Thanks for any hint on this!

**Update:**

I think I found a solution, feedback welcome.
Idea: Extract indices (position) of each BIG character. Put them in a set, create the power set P of this set. This gives all permutations of possible deletions (including duplicates for e.g. 1,2 and 2,1 and if 1 = 2 = same BIG character)

Comment: Not sure I understand this: I am only interested in unique permutations, that is, if the first or second A is removed makes no difference. Of course it however makes a difference if the first or last A is removed. Are _alAADBdBBDkCeCCA and Aal_ADBdBBDkCeCCA the same permutation (as just interested in characters order unimportant) or different?

Comment: @akaFlanners: Sorry, my fault. In this example it makes no difference if the second or third A is removed, as they "stand" together (AA without anything between). Regarding your updated comment: Those two permutations are different.

Comment: Regarding your solution: You will still need to filter out the duplicate strings. You could use a string set for this. But I wonder if there's a faster way/better algorithm. (+1 for the interesting problem)

Comment: Yes, I noted that, I use a Set<String> for the output, so it's no problem. For the moment I am lucky this problem could be reduced for another one, so at least coding it is not too much a problem. Also wondeirng if there's a better way though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar thoughts to your update but maybe your will end up more elegant than mine as I don't filter anything out

I'd started by making a kind of binary table of all the uppercase letters in the string (we can ignore the lowercase as they are never touched).

Start with really simple examples and work your way up.
In the binary table 0 means leave the character where it is and 1 means remove it.

e.g. for string of A (or any string with only 1 capital eg. aaaAa) 2 permutations

```
A
0
1
```

for AB (or string with 2 capitals aaaAaBbb) 4 permutations

```
AB
00
10
01
11
```

for ABC 8 permutations

```
ABC
000
100
010
110
001
101
011
111
```

for ABCD 16 permutations

```
ABCD
0000
1000
0100
1100
0010
1010
0110
1110
0001
1001
0101
1101
0011
1011
0111
1111
```

You'll see that these are 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4 2^numberOfUppercaseCharacters

This gives you the total number permutations without the removal of duplicates issue.
You could inelegantly implement a brute force approach that loops though each of the character positions switching off at the character - and saving the output string to a set. As it's in a set duplicates would not be added.

So take your input string
 parse it to get the index of each Uppercase character

In the binary tables above conceptually think about replacing A B C with the index positions in the string.

So

For string aaAbbBb we have index 2 and 5 (0 based index)

```
A B
_ _
0 0
1 0
0 1
1 1
```

becomes

```
2 5
_ _
0 0
1 0
0 1
1 1
```

So if we take representation of binary numbers up to 2^numOfUppercase and remove the associated value that should work. Note sample below has the string and the uppercase indexes list hardcoded. At least you have something to try and check your solution against.

Note no idea of upper bounds of this approach - may well fall over with long strings of uppercase characters as large binary representation of permutations.

Sample of that here:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class StringProcessing {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringProcessing sp = new StringProcessing();
    sp.setUpProcessing();

}

public void setUpProcessing() {
    String input = "aaABCDcs";

    //Populate with indexes of Uppercase letters (loop though each char and check if [A-Z])
    ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    indexes.add(2);
    indexes.add(3);
    indexes.add(4);
    indexes.add(5);

    Set<String> permutationStore = new HashSet<String>();
    BigInteger permutations = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(indexes.size());  //2^numOfUppercaseChars


    int maxSize = getMaxLength(permutations); //Need this for padding binary with 0

    for (BigInteger index = BigInteger.ZERO; index.compareTo(permutations) < 0;  index = index.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        String binary = index.toString(2);
       // System.out.println(permutations + " " + index + " " + binary + ", for string: " + input); //NumOf Permutations, currentPermutation, binaryRepresentation

        int lastIndex = binary.length() -1;
        StringBuilder currentString = new StringBuilder(input);
        String permutationString = process(lastIndex, binary, currentString, indexes, maxSize);
        permutationStore.add(permutationString);
        System.out.println(permutations + " " + index + "    " + binary + ", for string: " + input + ", Stored: " + permutationString);
    }

    System.out.println("");
    for(String s : permutationStore) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}

public int getMaxLength(BigInteger permutations) {
   BigInteger zeroBased = permutations.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
   return  zeroBased.toString(2).length();
}

public String process(int lastIndex, String binary, StringBuilder currentString, ArrayList<Integer> indexes, int maxSize) {
    int indexFound = binary.lastIndexOf('1', lastIndex);

    if (indexFound == -1) {
        return currentString.toString();
    }
    int padding =  maxSize - binary.length(); //Add leading "0's" to binary 

    int index = indexFound + padding;
    int charPos = indexes.get(index);

    currentString.deleteCharAt(charPos);
    process(indexFound-1, binary, currentString, indexes, maxSize);

    return currentString.toString();
}

}
```